# angular 13 - control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a code structure as below. I am using angular-material-autocomplete and marked it as "required".

I'm getting an error like this, what could be the reason for my error?

I did some research but the existing solutions didn't work for me. How can I fix this error?

```
 exports class MaterialDemandsComponent implements OnInit{
   workflows: WorkflowListModel[] = [];  //Workflow list
   ownerForm: FormGroup | any;
   workflowsCtrl = new FormControl();  //autoComplete states


  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.filteredStates = this.workflowsCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(""),
    map(state => (state ? this._filterStates(state) : this.workflows.slice())),
  );

  //Validators
  this.ownerForm = this.fb.group({
      description: [null, [Validators.maxLength(250), Validators.required]],
      workflowName:  this.fb.array( [ ["", Validators.required]]),
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <form [formGroup]="ownerForm">

    <!-- Workflow -> Approve Type-->
    <mat-form-field class="dialog-full-width" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Onay Tipi</mat-label>
      <input matInput
             required
             aria-label="Onay Tipi"
             [(ngModel)]="material.workflowName"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto"
             [formControl]="workflowsCtrl"
             formControlName="workflowName">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.displayName" (onSelectionChange)="setWorkflowInfo(state)">
          <span>{{state.displayName}}</span> | <small>{{state.id}}</small>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
      <mat-error>Nationality is required!</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
   </form>
```

[image]

Comment: what is `workflowsCtrl`? Also either use formControl of formControlName not both

Comment: also `workflowName` is an form array while it must be a form control.

Comment: hi, yes workflows is a series. Also added for workflowsCtrl formControl

Comment: Sure but then you cannot use `formControlName='workflowName'` as it is NOT a form control.

Comment: yes I couldn't :( at least how can I fix this error?

Comment: First, by removing     formControlName="workflowName".

Comment: you're great mate, I just removed the formControlName="workflowName" field and everything was fine. thank you so much